# Add class on img in settimeout with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

I have this for loop where I am creating a bunch of images to be used as an "emoji-rain"

```
var icons = ['balloon', 
             'clapping-hands-light-skin-tone', 
             'clapping-hands-medium-skin-tone', 
             'crazy-face', 
             'face-blowing-a-kiss', 
             'grinning-face-with-smiling-eyes', 
             'heart-suit',
             'money-bag',
             'man-dancing',
             'money-mouth-face',
             'money-with-wings',
             'party-popper',
             'victory-hand-light-skin-tone',
             'victory-hand-medium-dark-skin-tone',
             'woman-dancing'];

         for(i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

            left = (Math.random() * (document.querySelector('#site').offsetWidth) - 75);
            top = parseInt(Math.random() * (i * 125));

            img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = 'src/public/icons/rain/'+ icons[i] +'.svg';
            img.style.left = left +'px';
            img.style.top = top +'px';
            img.style.position = 'absolute';

            rainElement.appendChild(img);
    }
```

What I want is to add the class "fall" using `setTimeout` so that the icons will start to fall at different times.

I have this

```
(function(i) { 

   setTimeout(function() {

   img.addClass('fall');

  }, i*750);
 })(i);
}
```

But that will add "fall" only to the last element. I can't figure out how to do it on all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't put the `setTimeout` in the cycle, but rather create an external function, e.g.:

```
function fall(i) {
  return function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        img.addClass('fall');
    }, i * 750);
  }
}
```

and within the loop:

```
fall(i)();
```

The anonymous async function (setTimeout in this case) will have the value of `i` bound to the same variable outside the function, then you will have the class added only to the last element of the loop. What you want instead is to bind it to a value that doesn't change in the loop, and this is one way to do this.